# Dos "accordions" juntos uno no funciona

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo dos "accordions" uno al lado de otro el primero funciona pero el seguno no (los paneles no se cierran) Tienen diferente id y el css funciona en ambos. Supongo que es algo del jquery ui. pero no se que puede ser. Estan en una página con Boostrap. Agradecería algún dato gracias.

Comment: Quise decir segundo, no "seguno".

Comment: Hola, puedes [edit] tu propia pregunta para cambiarla. Además de corregir ese error tipográfico, debes añadir algo de código y un [mcve]. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información y consejos para mejorar esta pregunta. Es imposible ayudarte si no incluyes el código que te genera el error. Además, deberías clarificar mejor el problema: Bootstrap no usa jQuery UI, y si puedes estaría bien agregar los errores que veas en la consola.

Comment: qué versión de bootstrap usas?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder. Boostrap 3 es la versión que uso.

Comment: No tengo error en los acordeons por eso no pongo el código. Como bien explico uno funciona y el otro no funciona la animación de habrir y cerrar y eso me parece que esta dado por el jquery-ui.min.js.

Comment: ¿Cómo pego el código html?